# Hololens 2 & Unity - How can I get the CameraToWorld and Projection Matrices?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm using the Hololens 2 with Unity 2019.3.14. With the PhotoCaptureFrame class, I'm taking a picture, analyzing it to find a specific marker and then I create an hologram where the marker is. My code is working well with a webcam in the Unity Editor. But on the hololens, there is an offset between the hologram and the marker.

I tried to correct it with cameraToWorld matrix and the projection matrix, but it's not working (I always get the identity matrix). I thing it's related to this issue : https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/photocaptureframe-fails-to-provide-camera-matrices-on-hololens-2

```
photoCaptureFrame.TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix(out Matrix4x4 c2wMatrix);
photoCaptureFrame.TryGetProjectionMatrix(out Matrix4x4 projMatrix);
```

Some code the in the documentation that looks like mine : https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/windowsholographic-photocapture.html

My question is : Do you know of any alternative I could use to correct this offset ? I'm really stuck :/

Thanks in advance !

Comment: According to the status of this bug in issue tracker, the fix has been committed and pushed in the source control, and it will land in a Unity release in the future. We recommend you to wait for the fix in 2019.4.

Answer (score 1):

The bug was resolved with the Unity 2019.4.6 version

Answer (score 0):

Those two methods return bools as well as outputting the the matrices (if found), are they returning true for you? I haven't had any issues with the TryGetCameraToWorldMatrix method (don't think I've ever had it return false on me).

I know that you're only able to get to this point if OnCapturedPhotoToMemory is reached, but have you confirmed that the photo was taken and saved successfully?

Comment: Hi. The functions are returning false for me. The photo is taken successfully because I'm able to analyze it and detect the marker with another part of my code (I'm not saving the picture because I only need to analyze it)